# Merge adjacent row based on condition

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have tried other posts on this topic but cannot seem to find the correct solution.

I have a dataframe the describes a conversation seperated by speakers:

```
import pandas as pd
data = [[1, 'hello'], [2, 'hi there'], [1, 'how are you?'],[2, 'i am well'], [2, 'how are you?']] 
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['speaker', 'turn'])
```

What I am looking to do is merge adjacent rows where the same speaker label is present. In other words, I would like to be able to merge the last two rows as they should both count as the same conversational turn.

```
data = [[1, 'hello'], [2, 'hi there'], [1, 'how are you?'],[2, 'i am well', 'how are you?']
```

I suspect the answer involves the groupby function, but my attempts to get it working so far have not worked.

Comment: I suspect that even using `groupby`, you'd be better off using raw python. Although it may _look_ vectorized, `.str` functions in pandas generally aren't, and you'll just end up with extra overhead. I'd start by using [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) (and assigning back to a column if you want to keep the df format)

Comment: you only want to merge if the row above is has the same speaker id?

Comment: @Datanovice - that's right, I need to keep the order of the conversation, but am looking to merge occurances where the same speaker ID is used consecutively

Comment: @DC_Liv cool - I think almost all of the solutions below should sort you out, let me know if you need any additional help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Strings are not well-handled in Pandas; the operations may *look* vectorized but really they're not. In any case, all you want to do is aggregate the lists at this stage, and that format also doesn't fit nicely into a df where you expect scalar values. Use [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby)

```
import itertools

from operator import itemgetter


data = [[1, 'hello'], [2, 'hi there'], [1, 'how are you?'],[2, 'i am well'], 
        [2, 'how are you?']] 

rebuilt_list = []
for speaker, comment_group in itertools.groupby(data, itemgetter(0)):

    comments = [speaker] # To make sure you have the speaker id as first value

    for comment in comment_group:
        comments.extend(comment[1:])

    rebuilt_list.append(comments)
```

Answer (score 2):

Another implementation in pandas:

```
data = [[1, 'hello'], [2, 'hi there'], [1, 'how are you?'],[2, 'i am well'], 
    [2, 'how are you?']]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['id', 'text'])
df['new_text'] = np.where(df['id'] == df['id'].shift(-1), df['text']+' '+df['text'].shift(-1), df['text'])


result_df = df[df['id']!=df['id'].shift(1)][['id', 'new_text']]
result_df   

    id            new_text
0   1               hello
1   2              hi there
2   1            how are you?
3   2  i am well how are you?
```

Answer (score 1):

IIUC,

```
# get all occurrences where speaker is eq to above and below row.
s = df['speaker'].eq(df['speaker'].shift()) | df['speaker'].eq(df['speaker'].shift(-1))
# filter out the above rows and concat the frame with a groupby
print(
     pd.concat(
            [
                df.loc[~s],
                df.loc[s]
                .groupby("speaker")["turn"]
                .apply(lambda x: ",".join(x))
                .reset_index(),
            ]).reset_index())
```

Result

```
     speaker                  turn
0        1                   hello
1        2                hi there
2        1            how are you?
3        2  i am well,how are you?
```

you can edit the apply to match your desired result. (if you want space after comma)

as this is using apply it's not good for big datasets.